# Recursive way to order by in Many 2 Many

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion, sql-order-by

I have tables/records like this:

```
Table: COMMENTS
---------------------------------------------
COMMENT_ID | CONTENT            | CREATE_DATE
---------------------------------------------
      1    | Content 1          | 2016-09-01
      2    | Content 2          | 2016-09-02
      3    | Content 3          | 2016-09-03
      4    | Reply 2-1          | 2016-09-04
      5    | Reply 1-1          | 2016-09-05
      6    | Reply 1-1-1        | 2016-09-06


Table: REPLY_COMMENTS
---------------------------------
COMMENT_ID | REPLY_TO_COMMENT_ID
---------------------------------
     4     |         2
     5     |         1
     6     |         5
```

And I'd like to show the records like this order:

```
---------------------------------------------
COMMENT_ID | CONTENT            | CREATE_DATE
---------------------------------------------
      1    | Content 1          | 2016-09-01
      5    | Reply 1-1          | 2016-09-05
      6    | Reply 1-1-1        | 2016-09-06
      2    | Content 2          | 2016-09-02
      4    | Reply 2-1          | 2016-09-04
      3    | Content 3          | 2016-09-03
```

So the 'reply' contents should be under the parent's content - but the reply contents also should be ordered by CREATE_DATE.

Basically, I want to put together: content and reply with order of CREATE_DATE.

I wrote the query like this:

```
SELECT  comment.*
FROM COMMENTS comment
LEFT JOIN REPLY_COMMENTS reply_comment ON reply_comment.COMMENT_ID = comment.COMMENT_ID

ORDER BY (SOMETHING SHOULD BE HERE), comment.CREATE_DATE ASC
```

I can't write the order by clause with my current knowledge - please help me out (I'm using MySQL).

Comment: This is trickier than your [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313078/order-by-clause-for-many-2-many-in-mysql/39313156#39313156).  You might want to avoid storing comment versions in this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is impossible - so I ended up adding new column: `SEQNO` to the `COMMENTS` table.  The column will be updated when a new comment is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

If you always have space between char and numeric value then it works fine (for present data) otherwise you can try by using string functions in tricky ways:

```
COMMENT_ID  CONTENT        CREATE_DATE
----------  -------------  -----------
     1  Content 1      2016-09-01 
     2  Content 2      2016-09-02 
     3  Content 3      2016-09-03 
     4  Reply 2-1      2016-09-04 
     5  Reply 1-1      2016-09-05 
     6  Reply 1-1-1    2016-09-06 
     7  Reply 1-10-12  2016-09-06

SELECT  comment.*
FROM COMMENTS COMMENT
LEFT JOIN REPLY_COMMENTS reply_comment ON reply_comment.COMMENT_ID = comment.COMMENT_ID
ORDER BY REPLACE(content, LEFT(content, LOCATE(' ', content) - 1), '')

--OUTPUT--

COMMENT_ID  CONTENT        CREATE_DATE
----------  -------------  -----------
     1  Content 1      2016-09-01 
     5  Reply 1-1      2016-09-05 
     6  Reply 1-1-1    2016-09-06 
     7  Reply 1-10-12  2016-09-06 
     2  Content 2      2016-09-02 
     4  Reply 2-1      2016-09-04 
     3  Content 3      2016-09-03
```

Comment: Would this also work for revision numbers which have two digits, e.g. `1-10-12` ??

Comment: Please include a Fiddle with sample data.

Comment: Updated above please check, BTW you could try it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but we don't want to order by the content, the content can be anything

Comment: Yes, I have just gave the solution on your given data which is also difficult and you are right changing data environment it's really very difficult. It's tricky and tedious one requirement if we want so then we can simply prefix the numeric content and order by that otherwise we can add content_code column and save numeric value in that. At display time we can display by concatenation.